# Firebase Realtime Database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using the following rule to check that only 'admins' can write to the traps section.

```
"traps": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null  && root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() === true",
        },
```

This works fine.  However if I change the rule to the following,

```
"traps": {
    "$trap" : {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null  && root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() === true",
       }
    },
```

then I get a permission error. W/SyncTree: Listen at /traps failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied.

The reason I'm making this structure change is I'm trying to use the validate function but as I can't get past this first issue, I can't get as far as the validate.

```
"traps": {
    "$trap" : {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null  && root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() === true",
      "trapNumber": {
         ".validate": "newData.isString()"
       }
    }
},
```

I'm sure this is a rookie comprehension error but I've made little progress with this after trying many permutations.  You assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Update 20160629

Frank, the admin section looks as follows

```
admins
   somegeneratedkey: true
```

Comment: Can you add the following to your question: a snippet of the JSON (as text please) that you think should satisfy the `root.child('admin')` requirement, and the actual code for the write operation that fails.

Comment: I added the admin section above.  I actually solved this problem though last night.  Turns out I had a couple of problems.  By movin the .read down to the $trap level it meant I was no longer authorized to read the Trap level individually

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
"rules": {
    "traps": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null  && root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() === true",
    "$trap" : {
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['trapNumber']) && newData.child('trapNumber').isString()"
        }
    },
    etc.
```

I had to leave the read and write at the traps level as that was the level my database reference was using.

A little piece of additional information, isNumber() is not testing a String for a numeric value, it is testing that a numeric field (int) is passed.  Not the behavior I was expecting.